# Method of image charges for electric potential in a metallic disk

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, voltage, method-of-images

It is well known that the method of image charges is not always applicable, so I was wondering: is there an analytic way to calculate the electric potential for a point charge interacting with a perfectly conducting, neutral **(edited)** metallic disk using image charges? If it can be calculated or not, for what reason? Even if it could be solved, I don't think the method conforms to that of a conducting sphere, so I would like to know (if there is one) an analytical method that would allow it to be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics* section 3.12 "Mixed Boundary Conditions; Charged Conducting Disc." The method is actually the reverse of the method of images. Usually, the method consists of extending the domain of the problem by applying symmetries (reflections for planar conductors, inversion for the sphere etc.). Here, it is rather the opposite as the full domain is rather cut in half by adding mixed boundary conditions at the boundary.

Btw, the conducting disk can also be seen as the limit of a flattened conducting ellipsoid whose general solution is also known (but very complicated). This approach is presented in problem 2.57 of Griffiths' *Introduction to electrodynamics*. The derivation of the formula for an ellipsoid is referred to W. R. Smythe, Static and Dynamic Electricity, 3rd ed. (New York: Hemisphere, 1989), Sect. 5.02. for the calculation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, your answer is valuable, but most likely I have expressed myself wrongly. What I meant was not a charged metallic disk, but rather a perfectly conducting, neutral metallic disk.

Comment: If it’s neutral, the potential is uniform and the electric field is zero…

Comment: I misspoke again, sorry for my ineptitude. I mean: the electric potential of a point charge interacting with a neutral metal disk...

Comment: Oh ok I get it now. I think that by analogy with the sphere, it would be easier to first treat the grounded disk and then add Jackson’s solution if you want to fix the charge. I’ll think about it

Comment: Have you thought about it? Do you have any ideas about?